# Nativescript angular RadSideDrawer is undefined

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am working on Nativescript Angular and i have a `RadSideDrawer` for iOS device only. When i install the app, login and click on the button for `RadSideDrawer` i receive an error that `TypeError: sideDrawer.showDrawer is not a function. (In 'sideDrawer.showDrawer()', 'sideDrawer.showDrawer' is undefined)` . However when i hit `CTRL + S`  and the app restarts, the `RadSideDrawer` works fine. Any help is appreciated.

My code structure is similar to this sample project https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ZyeGeF&v=3

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, [force an Angular change detection cycle beforehand](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#!#detectChanges-anchor). Maybe you are executing the side drawer function before the component is available.

But, could you give us the exact code—or excerpts—in your question so we can better aid you?